# Is it possible to send SPL-Tokens to multiple addresses in 1 or multiple transaction with spltoken cli in Solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction

I've tried to do it using a .csv but couldn't get it to work, I've only used cli commands. I'm a beginner in coding (been doing it for roughly 2 months now). So if the only way is through code, please provide me it with explanation and/or documentation so I can learn from it.

I've attached the screenshots of my csv & error message:
[CLI Command + Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDNM2.png) & [CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn35q.png)

I've tried using solana-tokens cli & .csv file.

Comment: `solana-tokens` is designed to do exactly that, and the error says there's a problem with the CSV file, so be sure to read the error message and fix up your CSV file as needed

Comment: I got it to work, though I have to add 9 0's behind the number I want to transfer. So if I want to transfer 1 spl token, I have to write "1000000000", do you know any fixes for that? Turning it into a decimal doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like that's the way it works currently. It could probably be updated to use the decimals in the SPL token mint to parse numbers with decimals. The source code is at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/tokens if you want to make a change!